# Flutter mobile app dev- "the named parameter title' isn't defined. I have change it to label" but still getting error. What would be the problem?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation, flutter-appbar

**This is the code:**
Have changed title to label as below. But Text(....) was all highlighted in red. Error - "the argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'."

```
    @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var data = EasyLocalizationProvider.of(context).data;
  return EasyLocalizationProvider(
          data: data,
      child: Scaffold(
     body: callPage(currentIndex),
     bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
         data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
             canvasColor: Colors.white,
             textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                 caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(0.15)))),
         child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          fixedColor: Color(0xFF6991C7),
          onTap: (value) {
           currentIndex = value;
           setState(() {});
          },
BottomNavigationBarItem(
               icon: Icon(Icons.shop),
               label: Text(
                 AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('Produce'),
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Berlin", letterSpacing: 0.5),
               )),
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFRoz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace

```
label: Text(
   AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('Produce'),
   style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Berlin", letterSpacing: 0.5),
),
```

with

```
label: AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('Produce')
```

Answer (score 0):

`BottomNavigationBarItem`'s `lable` reveive `String` type, not `Text`.

[image]

Comment: How would I format the code to receive string type ? When I am remove text; I get error in the style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Berlin", letterSpacing: 0.5),

Comment: Change `lable: Text(...` to `label: AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('Produce')` should be fine.

Comment: Yes I did change that; but got error in the style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Berlin", letterSpacing: 0.5), - style was highlighted in red... The named parameter 'style' isn't defined.

Comment: You should replace whote Text with `AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('Produce')`

Comment: Checked my another answer? (I can not type all info in comment)

Answer (score 0):

Check in the documentation, the label is a string? and not a widget.
Link : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html
So you have to change it like this:

```
label: AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('Produce')
```